# Kalman filter on Timeseries

Tags: estimation, time-series, kalman-filter

After a lot of research on Kalman filter I can't find anywhere how exactly the filter works on timeseries.Specifically, I want to know about fοrecasting with Kalman filter on **Timeseries**, point estimation and forecast intervals or a simple example.If my question sounds general, it would be nice if someone tells me where to search about this topic.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: all you have to understand is that the Kalman filter is the optimal solution to the maximum likelihood problem for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Underlying_dynamic_system_model  (the only unknown to be estimated being the states $x_i$ ). when the model is non-linear or the noise is not perfectly gaussian and centered or the covariance matrices $Q_k$ are unknown,  then the (non-linear) kalman filter is NOT optimal, but still not so bad / useful in many  cases.

Comment: Thank you for your time.I care about linear models.The real question is:Is kalman filter only for one-step prediction?what's happening if i want to predict 2 steps ahead(then whats the point of "filtering" since i dont have the measurement)?example: if I have a AR(1) model --> Χ(2)=(φ^2)Χ for 2 steps ahead

Comment: the Kalman filter is optimal for the Apollo problem : how to know what is the expected position in space of the spaceship knowing only (with small errors) its velocity/acceleration at different timesteps and that at $t=0$ it was on earth and at $t=t1$ it was aligned with the earth and the moon ?

Comment: you notice that the model is linear : the position is a linear function of (noiseless) velocity and acceleration measurements

Comment: So if I have one and only measurement z1, can the calman filter make a prediction for the state x3 without knowing z2,z3?

Answer (score 0):

For time series use the discrete Kalman filter as described the chapter 4.1. [here](https://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Etracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf).

I guess the point is how to formulate a given problem as a Kalman problem which means achieving the following formulation out of the initial formulation of the problem:

[image]

I learned this problem reformulating challenge, especially when developing my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218048/what-is-kalman-filter/3880183#3880183).

The solution itself is IMHO well documented in the references. It’s executing or implementing the following algorithm:

[image]